# Ugly segmentation fault with getline()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++, getline

I need the `getline()` function for some white space, including text input by the user. But instead of the user input, I get a segmentation fault.

Here is a minimized example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

/**
 * Shows main menu.
 *
 * @version 1.0.0
 *
 * @return Returns selected option.
 */
unsigned int showMenu() {
    unsigned int result;
    printf("\n\nSimple transfer\n===============\n\n");
    printf("Options:\n-----------\n");
    printf(" 1: Receive\n");
    printf(" 2: Send\n");
    printf("Enter any other number to exit.\n\n");
    printf("?: ");
    scanf("%u", &result);
    return result;
}

// Some functions.

/**
 * Entry point.
 *
 * @version 1.2.0
 *
 * @return Returns result code.
 */
int main() {
    // Initialization.
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    bool expectData;
    std::string inMessage, outMessage;
    // Run.
    while (true) {
        switch (showMenu()) {
            // Receiving mode.
            case 1:
                // Some code.
                std::cout << "Received.\n";
                break;

            // Sending mode.
            case 2:
                outMessage = "Dies ist eine Testnachricht.";
                getline(std::cin, outMessage);
                printf("Sending: ");
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= outMessage.length() -1; i++) {
                    // Some code.
                    printf("%c", outMessage[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                break;

            // Exit.
            default:
                printf("Bye.\n");
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you initializing outMessage and then reading into it? What is the input that breaks the program?

Comment: Why are you using `printf` and `scanf` in C++ code? You aren't even consistent, since you are mixing it with use of the C++ IO library.

Comment: Always check the return value of scanf. See [this link](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) for further information. Also, you may want to use a debugger to find out where exactly your program is crashing.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and more about [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and [about GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) (which includes `g++`) and [`gdb`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Segmentation faults are beautiful. Especially compared to the alternative of the program silently corrupting memory.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `i <= outMessage.length() -1` is usually written `i < outMessage.length() `.

Comment: `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` Why?

Comment: @nicomp Just for testing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 This is because some of the code, i removed at this example, uses printf() and should write it letter by letter instead of waiting.

Comment: Ok so that line should have been removed from the [mcve] to narrow it down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use:

```
std::cin.ignore();
```

Before your `getline(...);`, because it is reading your new line character caused by hitting enter instead of letting you type the message. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186568/getline-skipping-first-even-after-clear) for more details.

You are getting `Expression: string subscript out of range` exception, because you are trying to subscript an empty string here: `printf("%c", outMessage[i]);`

EDIT: As @Johnny Mopp pointed out in the comment, `outMessage.length()` is returning size_t type, which is unsigned type. Then from unsigned 0 you are subtracting 1, overflowing it to a 'big' number, so the for loop tries to print the very long non-existent string.

Comment: Don't leave us in suspense. Tell us how to fix it. <g>

Comment: just to clarify: `size_t` is actually *always* an unsigned type

Comment: @PeteBecker I proposed a solution which makes example code work.

Comment: @CruzJean Yep, I've meant 'some' unsigned type

Comment: @Hawky -- sorry, I wasn't clear. `ignore()` is part of the solution; it removes the immediate problem. But what happens when someone just hits enter at the call to `getline()`, and the result is a zero-length string? The loop condition should be `i < outMessage.length()`.

Comment: @PeteBecker There are a lot of issues with this code, and yes you are right, loop condition is also wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker I will also fix this loop condition, thanks. ;-)